# Python - Find non mutual items in two dicts

Tags: python

Lets say I have two dictionaries:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

What's the most pythonic way to find the non mutual items between the two of them such that for `a` and `b` I would get:

```
{'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

I had thought:

```
{key: b[key] for key in b if not a.get(key)}
```

but that only goes one way (b items not in a) and

```
a_only = {key: a[key] for key in a if not b.get(key)}.items()
b_only = {key: b[key] for key in b if not a.get(key)}.items()

dict(a_only + b_only)
```

seams very messy.  Any other solutions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> dict(set(a.iteritems()) ^ set(b.iteritems()))
{'a': 1, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Note that if a and b contain different values for the same key, the outcome will be arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

Try with the [symetric difference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.symmetric_difference) of `set()` :

```
out = {}
for key in set(a.keys()) ^ set(b.keys()):
   out[key] = a.get(key, b.get(key))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
diff = {key: a[key] for key in a if key not in b}
diff.update((key,b[key]) for key in b if key not in a)
```

just a bit cheaper version of what you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> b = {'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
>>> keys = set(a.keys()).symmetric_difference(set(b.keys()))
>>> result = {}
>>> for k in keys: result[k] = a.get(k, b.get(k))
... 
>>> result
{'a': 1, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
```

Whether this is less messy than your version is debatable, but at least it doesn't re-implement symmetric_difference.